# ZigBee routing (NWK layer) modeling

Tags: routes, simulation, modeling, zigbee

So, I've started a project for analyzing the influence of the LQI (linq quality index) calculation approach in a ZigBee (mesh) network. The idea is to try to implement different LQI calculations based on various indicators in an effort to maximize some QoS.

The problem is I cannot find any modeling tool that gives me the possibility of modifying the current way LQI calculation is implemented as described in the specification.

I tried Riverbed's OPNET solution, but no such customization is available there. I didn't venture out and try any ns2/ns3 solution because ... well, ns (I'm a beginner in the whole WPAN business).

Currently, being an experienced programmer, I'm at a stage where I'm seriously considering actually **implementing** the whole thing! Ok, well, most of it, anyways (I would probably leave out the security and back-compatibility issues).

But, asking beforehand could prove to be more useful. So, is there such a modeling suite/IDE/system/... out there somewhere or should I just stop looking and face my cruel reality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so this doesn't stay open, I ended up using ns2. I did, however, stumble upon several articles that claimed they managed to change the LQI calculation in the Riverbed's OPNET solution, but I didn't investigate further since I was already deep into ns2. And, I haven't seen any other solutions other that the two during my study.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use [ZBOSS](http://zboss.dsr-wireless.com/projects/zboss/wiki/What_is_ZBOSS) (ZigBee Open Source Stack) as a starting point for your project, and modify the existing code for link quality calculations.